# Best way to have taskset assign a job to random cores?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have an application whose license limits it to 4 cores per instance, running on a 16 core box.  Several of these instances run in parallel.

Instances spin up and down throughout the day.  In .bash_profile the variable "START" is assigned to "taskset -c 0-3 rlwarp ..." and other scripts (or humans on the box) start up instances using $START.  The end result is when the box is under heavy load, you can end up with four cores pegged while the other 12 run idle.

I'd like to modify "START" to assign to have taskset assign to four random cores to help alleviate the issue.  Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If taskset can take a list of numbers one approach would be to do this to get a list of 4 random numbers:

```
$ for (( i=1;i<=16;i++ )) do echo $RANDOM $i; done|sort -k1|cut -d" " -f2|head -4
8
2
15
5
```

Another rough idea would be to find a root random number and add 3 to it like this:

```
$ baseCPU=$(for (( i=1;i<=13;i++ )) do echo $RANDOM $i; done|sort -k1|cut -d" " -f2 | head -1)
$ echo "taskset -c ${baseCPU}-$(expr $baseCPU + 3) rlwarp..."
```

#### Examples

```
$ baseCPU=$(for (( i=1;i<=13;i++ )) do echo $RANDOM $i; done|sort -k1|cut -d" " -f2 | head -1)
$ echo "taskset -c ${baseCPU}-$(expr $baseCPU + 3) rlwarp..."
taskset -c 1-4 rlwarp...

$ baseCPU=$(for (( i=1;i<=13;i++ )) do echo $RANDOM $i; done|sort -k1|cut -d" " -f2 | head -1)
$ echo "taskset -c ${baseCPU}-$(expr $baseCPU + 3) rlwarp..."
taskset -c 2-5 rlwarp...

$ baseCPU=$(for (( i=1;i<=13;i++ )) do echo $RANDOM $i; done|sort -k1|cut -d" " -f2 | head -1)
$ echo "taskset -c ${baseCPU}-$(expr $baseCPU + 3) rlwarp..."
taskset -c 12-15 rlwarp...
```

#### Ultimate solution

Chuu's final solution (as a 1-liner):

```
$ RTEST=$(($RANDOM % 16));\ 
   taskset -c "$((RTEST%16)),$(((RTEST + 1)%16)),$(((RTEST+2)%16)),$(((RTEST+3)%16))" rlwrap ...
```

#### How it works

Get a random number between 1-16:

```
$ RTEST=$(($RANDOM % 16));
$ echo $RTEST
3
```

Doing modulo division 4 times, adding 1 to $RTEST prior to allows us to increment the numbers to generate the range:

```
$ echo $((RTEST%16)),$(((RTEST + 1)%16)),$(((RTEST+2)%16)),$(((RTEST+3)%16))
3,4,5,6
```

Performing modulo division is a great way to box a number so that you get results in a specific range.

```
$ echo $((RTEST%16))
3

$ echo $(((RTEST + 3)%16))
6
```

Doing this guarantees that you'll always get a number that's between 1-16. It even handles the wrap around when we get random numbers that are above 13.

```
$ echo $(((14 + 3)%16))
1
```